# AES Encryption Java to iOs - With password, iv and salt

Tags: java, android, ios, encryption, aes

i'm developing an app for three platforms (Android, ios and WP8). This app connect with server and uses AES for security.

I have ready a test version for android and Windows Phone working good and the code generated (in base64) with android is decoded with the wp code and on the contrary.

But, on iOs i get other response with the same SALT, KEY and IV. This is my code for android:

```
public static SecretKeySpec generateKey(char[] password, byte[] salt) throws Exception {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 1024, 128);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
        return secret;
    }

public static Map encrypt(String cleartext, byte[] iv, SecretKeySpec secret) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    // If the IvParameterSpec argument is omitted (null), a new IV will be
    // created
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, iv == null ? null : new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
    byte[] usediv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(cleartext.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    Map result = new HashMap();
    result.put(IV, usediv);
    result.put(CIPHERTEXT, ciphertext);
    return result;
}


public static String decrypt(byte[] ciphertext, byte[] iv, SecretKeySpec secret) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    String plaintext = new String(cipher.doFinal(ciphertext), "UTF-8");
    return plaintext;
}

public static void main(String arg) throws Exception {
    byte[] salt = new byte[] { -11, 84, 126, 65, -87, -104, 120, 33, -89, 19, 57, -6, -27, -19, -101, 107 };



    byte[] interop_iv = Base64.decode("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==", Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] iv = null;
    byte[] ciphertext;
    SecretKeySpec secret; 
    secret = generateKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".toCharArray(), salt);
    Map result = encrypt(arg, iv, secret);
    ciphertext = (byte[]) result.get(CIPHERTEXT);
    iv = (byte[]) result.get(IV);
    System.out.println("Cipher text:" + Base64.encode(ciphertext, Base64.DEFAULT));
    System.out.println("IV:" + Base64.encode(iv, Base64.DEFAULT) + " (" + iv.length + "bytes)");
    System.out.println("Key:" + Base64.encode(secret.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    System.out.println("Deciphered: " + decrypt(ciphertext, iv, secret));

    // Interop demonstration. Using a fixed IV that is used in the C#
    // example
    result = encrypt(arg, interop_iv, secret);
    ciphertext = (byte[]) result.get(CIPHERTEXT);
    iv = (byte[]) result.get(IV);

    String text = Base64.encodeToString(ciphertext, Base64.DEFAULT);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Interop test - using a static IV");
    System.out.println("The data below should be used to retrieve the secret message by the receiver");
    System.out.println("Cipher text:  " + text);
    System.out.println("IV:           " + Base64.encodeToString(iv, Base64.DEFAULT));
    decrypt(Base64.decode(text, Base64.DEFAULT), iv, secret);
}
```

and this is my code for ios...i set a static IV and SALT like in Android code...but not found:

```
- (NSData*)encryptData:(NSData*)data :(NSData*)key :(NSData*)iv
{
    size_t bufferSize = [data length]*2;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
    size_t encryptedSize = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          [key bytes], [key length], [iv bytes], [data bytes], [data length],
                                          buffer, bufferSize, &encryptedSize);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:encryptedSize];
    else
        free(buffer);
    return NULL;
}

// ===================

- (NSData *)encryptedDataForData:(NSData *)data
                        password:(NSString *)password
                              iv:(NSData *)iv
                            salt:(NSData *)salt
                           error:(NSError *)error {

    NSData *key = [self AESKeyForPassword:password salt:salt];
    size_t outLength = 0;
    NSMutableData *
    cipherData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:data.length +
                  kAlgorithmBlockSize];

    const unsigned char iv2[] = {68, 55, -98, -59, 22, -25, 55, -50, -101, -25, 53, 30, 42, -20, -107, 4};

    CCCryptorStatus
    result = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, // operation
                     kAlgorithm, // Algorithm
                     kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, // options
                     key.bytes, // key
                     key.length, // keylength
                     iv2,// iv
                     data.bytes, // dataIn
                     data.length, // dataInLength,
                     cipherData.mutableBytes, // dataOut
                     cipherData.length, // dataOutAvailable
                     &outLength); // dataOutMoved

    if (result == kCCSuccess) {
        cipherData.length = outLength;
    }
    else {
        if (error) {
            error = [NSError errorWithDomain:kRNCryptManagerErrorDomain
                                         code:result
                                     userInfo:nil];
        }
        return nil;
    }

    return cipherData;
}

// ===================

- (NSData *)randomDataOfLength:(size_t)length {
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:length];

    int result = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault,
                                    length,
                                    data.mutableBytes);
    NSAssert(result == 0, @"Unable to generate random bytes: %d",
             errno);

    return data;
}

// ===================

// Replace this with a 10,000 hash calls if you don't have CCKeyDerivationPBKDF
- (NSData *)AESKeyForPassword:(NSString *)password
                         salt:(NSData *)salt {
    NSMutableData *
    derivedKey = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:kAlgorithmKeySize];

    int
    result = CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(kCCPBKDF2,            // algorithm
                                  password.UTF8String,  // password
                                  [password lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],  // passwordLength
                                  salt.bytes,           // salt
                                  salt.length,          // saltLen
                                  kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA1,    // PRF
                                  kPBKDFRounds,         // rounds
                                  derivedKey.mutableBytes, // derivedKey
                                  derivedKey.length); // derivedKeyLen
    // Do not log password here
    NSAssert(result == kCCSuccess,
             @"Unable to create AES key for password: %d", result);

    return derivedKey;
}
```

I convert data to base64 follows:

```
NSString* dataStr = [encryptedData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", dataStr);
```

**SOLUTION**

Finally i use this code on android and wp: http://www.dfg-team.com/en/secure-data-on-windows-phone-with-aes-256-encryption/

Comment: I don't see the ios Base64 encoding.

Comment: OK, so I thought that "it is not working" was the worst error description, but I guess "I'm getting other response" and "but not found" together now take the top spot. Please describe exactly what is happening.

Comment: Wait, that was too fast. Where is your `generateKey` method? Have you verified that the input arguments to your encryption routines is identical on both sides (by logging the hex. of the plaintext, key and IV right before the call?)

Comment: Yes I verified the data, but perhaps these data in objective c is changed (big endian, little endian...)

Comment: I'm following the next few steps: http://robnapier.net/aes-commoncrypto

Comment: hi,please provide me a code,i am facing same issue...

Comment: may be helpful this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/45539657/1321500 Thanks

Comment: This answer may helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/45539657/1321500 Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I already have a problem like yours. I just found the solution using this lib: https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor

Dont forget to validate the algorithm configuration in the file FBEncryptorAES.h

Comment: Thank you Sandro, I get the solution here  http://www.dfg-team.com/en/secure-data-on-windows-phone-with-aes-256-encryption/ , now, i know much of this, if you have questions, tell me.